# Data structure to hold paired values

Tags: java, data-structures

This is what I am trying to do :

Having a list of channel names where each channel name has several members. Both are Strings.

What I am doing now is having a 2d ArrayList.First value on each ArrayList is the channel name and next are its members. Is there a better way to do this (without creating classes) ?

Can a Map have many values for one key ? So that I have a channel as Key and members as Values to that Key ?

Thanks !

Comment: *"without creating classes"* Why? Anyway you can just have a `Map<String, List<String>>`. You'd only need to fiddle with adding/finding items associated with a channel name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  a Java `Map` can have any types of keys or values.

What you probably want here is a `Map<String, Set<String>>` (since I assume a channel cannot have the same member twice, right?).

And any really means any: you may even have `Map`s as keys to `Map`s.

Comment: Should have thought of that ... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Guava's [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) can be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `Map<String,ArrayList>`

Comment: Always use interfaces! Map<String,List<String>>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `Map<String, List<T>>` where `T` is the channel member type.